# Get current date and time form mktime in PHP

Tags: php, time

I have a problem with find the current date from past `mktime`. In PHP I find the current date using **`date("j");`**. Here I need, suppose my date was in the past year like `mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2008)`, then here how can I find the current date of this particular past month.

Comment: Are you looking for current date? or past month's date? or mktime()'s date?

Comment: I need Past/future months current date. I need current date as per mktime();

Comment: Current means now. Past/future means not now. Past/future cannot be current.

Comment: Suppose i create Calendar in PHP, here i need to show the current date of the past month or future moth, when i selected the month that time i need to show the current date.

Comment: For example, it's currently July 25th, and you want to select June 25th or August 25th? What do you want to find out about them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either as @octern's solution, or you can do

```
$day = date('j', strtotime("-2 months"));
```

or

```
$day = date('j', strtotime('-30 days'));
```

depending on your need.

You may also want to refer to [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) manual.

Comment: This looks like it solves a completely different problem from my answer. It could be what the poster is looking for, though -- the question still seems ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$date = getdate(mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2008));
$day = $date['mday'];
```

Or just:

```
$day = date('j', mktime(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2008))
```

Comment: it's display only 1, not display the current date of the mktime()